# NameError but variable is defined

Tags: python, defined

I'm writing this as a Python practice exercise.  The loop is supposed to take user input and evaluate it using the eval function, and break from the loop when the user enters *done*.  Returns the input that was prior to the input *done*.

```
def eval_loop():
    while True:
        x = ('done')
        s = (input("write a thing. "))
        s1 = s
        print(eval(s))
        if s == x:
            break
    return s1

eval_loop()
```

The code works fine for input such as *5*, *10 + 3*, etc.  But when I enter *done* as input, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rosem/Progs/1101D4.py", line 11, in <module>
    eval_loop()
  File "C:/Users/rosem/Progs/1101D4.py", line 6, in eval_loop
    print(eval(s))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'done' is not defined
```

Comment: If you are only using `x` to check if the input == 'done', then just do `if s == 'done':`

Comment: @Haveaniceday you meant `if s == 'done':`, right

Comment: Where did you learn to use `eval` in this way? You almost certainly do not want to use `eval` on arbitrary user input.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever use `eval` in general!!! It's extremely unsafe, and is unneeded in 99% of cases. [This StackOverflow post gives more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/11483682)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't eval 'text' like that. And I honestly suggest you don't use eval for such a problem anyway. But if you had to, you can switch the order and have a try/catch.

```
def eval_loop():
    while True:
        x = ('done')
        s = input("write a thing. ")
        s1 = s
        #check if input is 'done'
        if s == x:
            break
        else:
            try:
                #evaluate
                print(eval(s))
            #error caused by s being something like 'foo'
            except NameError:
                pass 
    return s1
eval_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NameError: name 'done' is not defined` is happening because you are not checking to see if the input was `done` before using `eval`. Instead try this:

```
def eval_loop():
    while True:
        s = (input("write a thing. "))
        s1 = s
        if s == 'done':
            break
        print(eval(s))

    return s1

eval_loop()
```

If you don't check then python tries to "run" `done`, which throws the error.

Also see Brain's comment and the other answer.